# PHP IIS App Pool and URL Rewrite

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis, application-pool

We have a php application running on Windows 2012 R2 and IIS 8.5.9600.16384.  The php application uses CodeIgniter as the MVC framework.  We are also using the IIS URL Rewrite module to remove the "index.php" from the url.

Over the past couple of months we have noticed that at apparently random times the URL Rewrite module will stop working, thus causing a 404 error page to appear because the url does not contain index.php as designed.  Simply recycling the app pool corrects the issue but we are having to monitor this all the time.  We have adjusted multiple settings on the app pool in attempts to correct the issue without success.  We have the exact same url rewrite rules in place on other applications and they do not have the same issue, which leads us to "it is something in the code of the php app" but we are struggling with any code that would cause the app to stop processing the url rewrite.  If we do not recycle the app pool and manually add in the "index.php" in the url, the 404 error does NOT occur.  So the application is still functioning, just not correcting the url.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have tried adjusting the recycle settings for the app pool too?

Comment: Yes.  We feel like we've tried everything.  We tried settings, we set the App Pool to recycle itself periodically.  Etc.  We aren't even convinced the App Pool is the problem.  We just know that recycling it corrects our rewrite issue.  Only reason we went the App Pool route in the first place was that this started happening.  We figured, let's put each app in it's own pool.  At least that way, all of our users of all 4 apps won't be affected when this happens.  That part worked.  We have 4 app pools.  Only 1 has to be recycled on a regular basis.